# x86 Assembly - whole number rounding issues

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to round to the nearest whole number for my assignment in assembly language and I've been spinning my wheels trying to figure it out. If for example I perform a division function 137/6, how do I get the result to round to the nearest whole number?

Comment: How are you doing the division? Show some code..

Comment: Do integer division as usual, check whether remainder is greater than half of divisor, if yes add one to result.

Comment: Some code to see what you're trying would be helpful (signed/unsigned division?  Floating point?)

Comment: For integer division of numbers `x = floor(x/y)*y+rem(x/y)` you only get the `floor(x/y)`-part. If you want a different result, you can modify x in relation to y before the division. For example: `ceil(x/y) = floor((x+y-1)/y)`.

Comment: `Q = (N + (D + 1) / 2) / D` rounds to nearest as 'fairly' as `Q = (N + D / 2) / D`, but any integer rounding scheme will introduce 'bias'. So you may need to consider tie-breaking strategies. e.g., does `135 / 6` round up or round down? Either choice will introduce bias - which might not matter for your purposes.

Comment: @BrettHale adding `(1+divisor)/2` *isn't* fair. Consider `137/5 = 27.4 -> 27`. If you add half the divisor you get `(137+2)/5 = 27.8 -> 27`, but if you try `(1+divisor)/2` you get `(137+3)/5 = 28.0 -> 28` which is incorrectly rounded up.

Answer (score 3):

For positive values add half the denominator to the numerator *before* the division. I leave the more complex situation of negative values to you.

```
mov ecx, [denominator]      ; divisor
mov eax, ecx                ; copy to numerator register
shr eax, 1                  ; half divisor
add eax, [numerator]        ; add to numerator
div ecx                     ; (numerator + denominator/2) / denominator
```

Answer (score 2):

"[Round half towards positive infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up)" for a positive number (explanations in the comments):

```
xor edx, edx                ; Clear EDX for division
mov eax, [numerator]        ; Dividend stored in the data section (eg. dd 137)
mov ecx, [denominator]      ; Divisor stored in the data section (eg. dd 6)
div ecx                     ; EDX:EAX / ECX = EAX remainder EDX
shl edx, 1                  ; EDX *= 2
cmp edx, ecx                ; Fraction part < 0.5 (remainder*2 < divisor) ?
jb .done                    ; Yes: skip rounding
add eax, 1                  ; No: round half up (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up)
.done:                      ; EAX = rounded result of division
```